# User Credentials Validation Error and Update With Media Error using CodeBird PHP

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

i want to check user credentials after user login in a form, then if username and password correct, user will redirected to upload.php page, and after upload an image and a status, image and status will post on user twit

here's my code for verifikasi.php

```
<h2>Verifikasi ID Twitter...</h2>
/*verification of user credentials
after validation of username and password success, redirect to upload image and status page
but if validation of username and password fail, back to login page
*/

<?php

require_once('codebird.php');
$cb = new \Codebird\Codebird;

$id = $_POST['id'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

 //if($_POST['loginTwitter'] == "Submit"){
 //if(isset($_POST['loginTwitter'])){
 if(isset($id) && isset($pass)){
    //cek bener apa engga nya

    //if($_POST['id'] == '' || $_POST['pass'] == ''){ header('login.php'); }

    $cb::setConsumerKey('somekey', 'somekeysecret');
    $cb::getInstance();
    $cb->setToken('tokenaccess', 'tokenaccesssecret');

    $code = $cb->account_verifyCredentials();
    if($code == 200){ 
        //$reply = $cb->oauth2_token();
        //$bearer_token = $reply->access_token;
        header('upload.php');
    }
    else{ header('login.php'); }

  //echo "Redirect to Upload Image...."; for($i = 0; $i <= 20000000; $i++); header('upload.php');
 }

 else{
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<h3>Something went wrong... Please Check Again Your Credentials</h3>";
  }

?>
```

and here's the post.php page (for posting image and status to user twit using update_with_media API

```
<div id="photo_tweet">
<h2>Photo Tweet</h2>
<br />

<?php require_once('codebird.php'); ?>

<?php
  function redirectToUpload(){
    echo "Redirect...";
    for($i = 0; $i <= 20000000; $i++);
    header('upload.php');
  }
?>

<?php
$imgExt = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$currImgExt = end( explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]) );

if($_POST['uploadTwit'] == "Submit"){

 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || $_POST['status'] == '')
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($currImgExt, $imgExt))
 {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        redirectToUpload();
    }
    else{
          $params = array(
            'status' => $_POST['status'],
            'media[]' => $_FILES["file"]["name"]
          );

          /*
          $data_user = array(
            'user_id' => ,
            'screen_name' => 
          );
          */
       $reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
    }
  }
 }
 else { echo "Invalid Image File or Invalid File Size or Twit cannot empty! Please check agian your image file before proceed!"; redirectToUpload(); }
?>

<p>You Just Succeed Post image and status!</p>

</div>
```

The problem for verifikasi.php is
Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in C:\wamp\www\twcodebird\verifikasi.php on line 36

i want to return status code in verifikasi.php, if code = 200 then user redirected to upload.php page,
but looking from error return, it seems my code wrong return... what should i do?

for post.php i'm not run it yet, because i want to make sure verification of user credentials work first

Comment: You have not mentioned the problem you are facing.

Comment: thx for remind me, i already edit my question